# What is the meaning of "Swasti na Indro Vridhhashravaha..."?

Tags: vedas, scripture, gods, sanskrit

This mantra is very famous, mostly also used in TV shows while showing Yajnas. This is also known as Shanti Path Mantra:

> ॐ भद्रं कर्णेभिः शृणुयाम देवाः ।
>   भद्रं पश्येमाक्षभिर्यजत्राः ।
>   स्थिरैरङ्गैस्तुष्टुवागँसस्तनूभिः ।
>   व्यशेम देवहितं यदायूः ।
>   **स्वस्ति न इन्द्रो वृद्धश्रवाः ।
>
>   स्वस्ति नः पूषा विश्ववेदाः ।
>
>   स्वस्ति नस्ताक्षर्यो अरिष्टनेमिः ।
>
>   स्वस्ति नो ब्रुहस्पतिर्दधातु ।
>
>   ॐ शान्तिः शान्तिः शान्तिः** ।।
>   
>   Om Bhadram Karnebhiḥ Srinuyaam Devah।
>   Bhadram Pashyem Akshabhir Yajatrah।
>   Sthirair Angais Tushtuvagamsas Tanoobhih।
>   Vyashema Devahitam Yadaayooh।
>   **Swasti Na Indro Vriddhashrava।
>
>   Swasti Na Poosha Vishwa-Vedaah।
>
>   Swasti Nastaaksharyo Arishtanemih।
>
>   Swasti No Brihaspatir-dadhaatu।
>
>   Om, Shaanti Shaanti Shaanti।।**

**From where are these mantras taken? And what are their meanings ?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This whole mantra forms the first passage of Taittariya Aranyaka of YajurVeda. The first verse "Om Bhadram Karnebhi Srinuyaam Devaha" also exists in RigVeda 1.89.8

Here is the meaning of the above mantra:

> ॐ भद्रं कर्णेभिः शृणुयाम देवाः ।
>   *Om Bhadram Karnebhiḥ Srinuyaam Devah*
>
> > **Om, May we hear what is Auspicious with our ears,Oh Gods**
>
> भद्रं पश्येमाक्षभिर्यजत्राः
>   *Bhadram Pashyem Akshabhir Yajatrah*
>
> > **May we see what is Auspicious With our eyes, Oh holy ones worthy of Worship**
>
> स्थिरैरङ्गैस्तुष्टुवागँसस्तनूभिः
>   *Sthirair Angais Tushtuvagamsas Tanoobhih*
>
> > **May we live a life of satisfaction with strong organs and Healthy body**
>
> व्यशेम देवहितं यदायूः
>   *Vyashema Devahitam Yadaayooh*
>
> > **May we Praise the Lord during the life span given to us by the Gods**
>
> स्वस्ति न इन्द्रो वृद्धश्रवाः
>   *Swasti Na Indro Vriddhashravah*
>
> > **May God Indra of Great fame bless us**
>
> स्वस्ति नः पूषा विश्ववेदाः
>   *Swasti Na Poosha Vishwa-Vedaah*
>
> > **May the Omniscient Poosha bless us**
>
> स्वस्ति नस्ताक्षर्यो अरिष्टनेमिः
>   *Swasti Nastaaksharyo Arishtanemih*
>
> > **May the Protector Garuda bless us**
>
> स्वस्ति नो ब्रुहस्पतिर्दधातु
>   *Swasti No Brihaspatir-dadhaatu*
>
> > **May Lord Brihaspati protect us**
>
> ॐ शान्तिः शान्तिः शान्तिः
>   *Om, Shaanti Shaanti Shaanti*
>
> > **Om, Peace, Peace, Peace**

Hence in a single paragraph the mantra means:

> Om, May we hear what is Auspicious with our ears,Oh Gods. May we see what is Auspicious With our eyes, Oh holy ones worthy of Worship. May we live a life of satisfaction with strong organs and Healthy body. May we Praise the Lord during the life span given to us by the Gods. May God Indra of Great fame bless us. May the Omniscient Poosha bless us. May the Protector Garuda bless us. May Lord Brihaspati protect us. Om, Peace, Peace, Peace

<sub>Refrences used from [here.](http://aumamen.com/mantra/om-bhadram-karnebhih-shrinuyama-devah)</sub>

Comment: It's [Shanti Mantra/Path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shanti_Mantra#Mundaka_Upanishad.2C_Mandukya_Upanishad_and_Prashna_Upanishad) of Atharva Veda; you can find in Prashna, Mundak and Mandukya Upanishads.

Comment: @Pandya it's not only of Atharvaveda.... as I have mentioned above it's in Taittariya Aranyaka... ie. It is also in YajurVeda...

Comment: Why Arishtanemi is translated as Garuda? Arishtanemi is the 22nd tirthankara of Jainism and is in no way related to Garuda.

Comment: @Chinmay Sarupria (Swasti=Bless; Nas=us; Taaksharyo=Garuda; Arishtanemih=Protector from evil)... although Taaksharyo doesn't exactly translate into Garuda... It means mythical bird ( may be related to Garuda)... see here http://www.greenmesg.org/mantras_slokas/vedas-om_bhadram_karnnebhih.php

Comment: I always wanted the meaning of this chant.. Thank you! Just a small correction pls. It is "swasthinastaarkshyo" and not Swasthinastaakaryo... _/\_

Comment: sorry ... not swasthinastaaksharyo...